# Canonical Transformation View Of Hamilton-Jacobi Theory

Tags: mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian, differential-equations

I came across the following proposition while reading Goldstein, in chapter 10, page 430, on Hamilton Jacobi theory. Here he performs a canonical transformation and he asserts that,

> We can automatically ensure that the new variables are constant in time by requiring that the transformed Hamiltonian, $K$, **shall be identically zero**, for then the equations of motion are $$\frac{\partial K}{\partial P_i}=\dot{Q_i}=0  , \qquad -\frac{\partial K}{\partial Q_i}=\dot{P_i}=0 .\tag{10.1} $$

I have a few questions,

- How do we know such a Canonical transformation exists so that $K$ is identically zero?
- From what I see, Hamilton Jacobi theory helps to solve the initial value problem **locally**. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is correct: Given certain regularity conditions, we are generically only guaranteed the existence of a **local** solution to the [Hamilton-Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) 1st-order non-linear [PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation).

Comment: Thank you for answering. What about my first question? How do we know such a C-T exists?

Comment: The solution $S$ to HJ eq. is a type 2 generating function for the sought-for CT.